# Open specific Test Plan, Test Case and Test Result in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

Is there any way to call/start TFS 2010's Test Manager with either a given Test Plan, a Test Case or Test Result to be opened?

What I want to do is to do some sort of evaluations on those items, but want to give the user the option to 'view' the underlying element natively.

Comment: Note that Test Case is a work item type, so could be viewed with anything that can view a work item.

Comment: John, yes.. but I am particularly interested in whether and how it's possible to do that with MTM, especially regarding Test Plan & Test Results/Points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you invoke any Browser (I tried with Firefox & IE) something like this:

```
mtm://tfsName:8080/tfs/CollectionName/p:TeamProjectName/testing//testplan/open?id=123
mtm://tfsName:8080/tfs/CollectionName/p:TeamProjectName/testing//testcase/open?id=123
mtm://tfsName:8080/tfs/CollectionName/p:TeamProjectName/testing//testrun/open?id=123
```

MTM will load with respecting view opened (testplan 123, testcase 123, testrun 123)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! -Just- before seeing your answer here, I stumbled upon the VS blog entry at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2010/02/09/sharing-content-in-microsoft-test-manager.aspx which provides the full specifics.

Comment: Yes, the full answer to your question lays in the article you mention.